# When mining text for keywords, is it faster to scan a list n times or compare each part of the list with n strings?

Tags: data-structures, web-scraping, time-complexity

I am scanning a list of words to tally the number of occurrences of each of n keywords. Is it faster to scan this list of words n times, each time scanning for one word, or to iterate through the list once but to compare each word with my n keywords?

Answer (score 1):

let there be P words in text.
Case 1:n*P times
Case 2:P*n times
I think it's better if u just hash it